# Elixir phoenix debugging leads to interactive shell instead of pry

Tags: debugging, elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-iex

I've been trying to debug a phoenix application.
To do so I used the following instructions:
- To set a break point: `require IEx; IEx.pry`
- To start a debugging server: `iex -S mix phx.server`

The problem comes when starting the server, the above instruction leads me to the elixir interactive shell (`iex(1)>`) and does not allow the server to run, from here if I execute the code manually it stops in the prys but I was hopping to have the server running and stop whenever a request hit the pry. Is there any solution?

I am currently using earlang 1.20, elixir 1.5 and phoenix 1.3

Comment: Where did you add `IEx.pry`?

Comment: I placed the IEX.pry inside a function in a controller

Comment: `iex -S mix phx.server` should drop you into an iex session but should also start the server at port 4000 (or whatever you have it configured). You can't open localhost:4000 after running that?

Comment: That's exactly the issue, after running iex -S mix phx.server localhost:4000 does not open @Dogbert

Comment: Where exactly did you put IEx.pry? Are you sure you are not opening the page routed to the action with breakpoint? Also, check if you have another tab/browser opened with localhost:4000, maybe something else is opening the page and causing break.

Answer (score 1):

It is common behavior that the `iex -S mix phx.server` command opens an IEx shell. It runs the web server on the port configured for the Phoenix endpoint within the respective `MIX_ENV` simultaneously to that. For each `IEx.pry()` breakpoint it executes, it should prompt on the command line whether you want to open an IEx shell there.

Check which `MIX_ENV` your server is running in, e.g. by typing the following in the IEx shell:

```
Mix.env
```

And then find the configuration in the files within the `config/` directory. The line should look like this:

```
config :nameofyourapp, Web.Endpoint,
  http: [port: 4000],
```

Maybe something other than 4000 is configured there? Or maybe some other application, or even a previously started instance of your web application already listens on that port and therefore prohibits the debug server from binding on that port? In that case, shutdown other running `mix phx.server` processes.